# How to randomly sample two columns based on percentages and assign labels?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x   y   location
21 10   ny
12 22   ny
32 90   cha
33 14   cha 
...
```

I want to randomly sample the rows of `x` and `y` columns based on percentages. I want 30% of the rows of `x` and `y` to be randomly assigned `group1` and 70% to be randomly assigned `group2`. Something like this:

```
x   y   location  group
21 10   ny        group1
12 22   ny        group2
32 90   cha       group2
33 14   cha       group2
...
```

I think I can do this with `mutate()` but I don't know how to write such code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your expected output does not match your specification.  (1) You have allocated 25% of obs to group 1 and 75% to group2.  (2) You have not sampled and rows, merely allocated them to a group.  Sampling would reduce the number of rows in the output data frame.  (3) What do you want to do when the number of rows in the input is not a multiple of 10?

Comment: Hi @Limey, the input dataframe is just an example. I have several thousand rows in my real dataframe. I'm sorry, I may have used 'sample' wrong - what I mean is, is that I want 30% of the rows to be randomly assigned group1 and 70% to be randomly assigned group2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` and assign the probability of occurrence of group using the `prob` argument.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
   mutate(group = sample(c('group1', 'group2'), n(), 
                          replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7)))
```

Since `sample` uses probability if you have 100 rows in `df` not necessarily exact 70 rows would always be assigned to `'group2'`. As the number of rows increase this probability would take you closer to 70%.

If you want exact 70%-30%  partition use `rep` instead.

```
n <- round(nrow(df) * 0.7)
df <- df %>% mutate(group = sample(rep(c('group1', 'group2'), c(n() - n, n))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `base R`

```
df <- transform(df, group = sample(c("group1", "group2"), nrow(df),
            replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7)))
```